# Windows Explorer 25% CPU usage while computer is idle?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, windows-explorer

I am facing a problem with my Windows Explorer.

I cannot figure out why this happens even if the computer is idle. When I try to run some games that are old(released before 2005), at first trial the game doesn't run but Explorer starts using 25%(1 Core) of my CPU.

When I double click the same file once again, this time, it runs without any issues. This finally boils down to try to run a game twice, and when it runs successfully, minimize the game and terminate Explorer and restart it.

My Dell laptop has :

- Windows 7 Ultimate(x64)
- 2nd Gen i7
- ATI Radeon HD 7650 1GB
- 8 GB RAM
- 500 GB SSD drive

My laptop is only 3 months old.

One more thing that I think is worth to be mentioned, the issue only occurs when I run old games some of which are :

- Max Payne 1
- Max Payne 2 : The Fall of Max Payne
- Manhunt : Born to Kill
- Project IGI

However, newer games like :

- Max Payne 3
- Dishonored : Knife of Dunwall
- Dishonoured
- All versions of Assassin's Creed.
- All new versions of Call of Duty 4
- Battlefield 3
- Price of Persia's all versions.

run without any troubles. All of them are original DVD's, not cracked versions. And I don't know which of them are 16/32/64 bit as it is not mentioned anywhere on the games covers.

Comment: It helps naming the games. Also, are they 16 or 32 bit?

Comment: They are surely 32bit. All are from years 2000-2004 built for P3/P4

Comment: follow this: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD and upload the compressed ETL file.

Comment: have you created the etl file?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for you help,but I found the cause while I was searching the net for something.The problem was due a hidden malware in the **Windows** folder,which my freaky antivirus was unable to find.

Comment: ok, post this as answer and mark it as answer.